# Print current view vs. current page

Tags: acrobat

We have a [.pdf file with a barcode](http://SwatchDog.com/BarcodeProblem.pdf) on it and (I know this sounds crazy but) when printing with current view, it prints correctly but when printing the current page it prints incorrectly.

The left-most character of the barcode is different.

My coworker has Acrobat 9.5 Pro and I have Acrobat Reader 11.0.12.

Comment: Could you specify "correctly" and "incorrectly" in your case?